# Is it correct that the US wants to form a new branch in the US Military as US Space Force?

Tags: military, united-states, space-force

I read in the news sometimes ago that Mike Pence proposed to form a new division in the US military as US Space Force. So I want know how it could be possible cause the space is not necessarily a premise of the US government in order to militarize it. Any idea or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Related reading: https://www.rollingstone.com/tv/tv-news/neil-degrasse-tyson-space-force-colbert-722935/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I read in the news sometimes ago that Mike Pence proposed to form a new division in the US Army as US Space Force.

It's not just Mike Pence. It's also Donald Trump, and also members of Congress. The only differences I can see between the Space Force currently proposed by the administration and the Space Corps previously proposed by members of Congress is the name, and that the Space Force has backing all the way from the top while the Space Corps proposals died in committee.

The advocates claim that this would cure some of the ills that currently plague the US military with regard to space. They do not want to militarize space; that goal was accomplished shortly after the first launch in the 1950s. The US is not alone in this regard; every key spacefaring nation has a military space operation.

One key issue is that space development, operations, and analysis are currently spread across all five branches of the military (the Army, Navy, Marines, Air Force, and Coast Guard), plus across various defense agencies that are not a part of any of those five branches such as the Defense Intelligence Agency, National Geospatial Intelligence Agency, National Reconnaissance Office, and National Security Agency. The argument is that a reorg would make things more efficient and more responsive.

Some are opposed to the idea, and not because it represents a militarization of space. (Note that the Space Corps proposal died in committee in a Republican dominated Congress.) The opposition instead claims that reorganizing the Department of Defense to have a sixth branch of the military would not solve the key problems that currently confront DoD with regard to space development, operations, and analysis.

If formed, the US Space Force would not be a division of the US Army. It would be a separate branch of the military. There would be no reason to make it a branch of the Army; most US military space efforts are currently under the US Air Force. About 85% of the non-black parts of the US military space efforts come under the auspices of the Air Force.

How this will all play out is to be determined. One thing that is certain: Forming a new branch of the US military is something that requires congressional approval.

Comment: The Air Force in particular is not happy with this idea. Whether you call it the Space Corps or the Space Force, the proposal is a very hard slap in the Air Force's  face. It implicitly accuses the Air Force of doing such a bad job with its Space Command that the Space Command needs to be ripped away from the Air Force.

Comment: Another reason might be that the Air Force is hogging "it's" resources, when it's unclear why it would need space resources (like communications or GPS satellites) more than other branches.

Comment: "One key issue is that space development, operations, and analysis are currently spread across all five branches of the military [...] plus across various defense agencies that are not a part of any of those five branches" [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: @SF. - That's XKCD is essentially the argument this proposal's critics make: It's the wrong cure and might well make problems worse.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear so, and in particular the 2020 re-election team has been busy with designing logos (an essential step in any new enterprise):

[Donald Trump's 2020 re-election team offers up 'Space Force' logo options for merchandise](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-08-10/trump-2020-to-sell-space-force-merchandise/10107190)

[Trump 2020 to sell 'Space Force' merch](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/08/09/politics/trump-campaign-space-force/index.html)

Facebook appears to have plenty of T-shirt merchandise already. Pew pew.